# I am trying to create a set of pop of windows to determine a varying number of xy coords

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a series of two pop of windows where the first will determine the number of coordinates the user will input and the second will allow the user to input this exact number of coordinates.

My code for the first pop up works and looks like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("User Inputs")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

numofcoord = StringVar()

numofcoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=numofcoord)
numofcoord.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="OK", command=user_coordinates).grid(column=1,    row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="CANCEL", command=quit).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Number of Coordinates").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

The first section works, but in the second section, my pop up looks like this where the number of rows is determined by the input in the first pop up window.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxq9G.png

the code for the second section looks like this:

```
try:
    noc = int(numofcoord.get())
    root = Tk()
    root.title("User Defined Coordinates")

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    x = StringVar()
    y = StringVar()

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="X").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Y").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

    for i in range(2, noc + 2):
        xcoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=x)
        xcoord.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

        ycoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=y)
        ycoord.grid(column=2, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="OK", command=test).grid(column=1, row=noc + 3, sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="CANCEL", command=quit).grid(column=2, row=noc + 3, sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()

except ValueError:
    pass
```

The issue is that in when you put a value in either the X or Y column, every box in that column is filled with that value and I would like for each row to be a set of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your entry widgets share the same `StringVar`.  You need to create a new instance of `StringVar` for each entry widget. Though, you don't really need to use `StringVar` at all. All you really need to do is keep a reference to each entry widget.

For example:

```
x_entries = []
y_entries = []

for i in range(2, noc + 2):
    xcoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7)
    xcoord.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

    ycoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7)
    ycoord.grid(column=2, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

    x_entries.append(xcoord)
    y_entries.append(ycoord)
```

Later, you can get the values like this:

```
print("first pair: ", x_entries[0].get(), y_entries[0].get())
```

You can do the same thing by using `StringVar`, but in most cases that adds complexity by giving you more objects to manage but without giving any real benefit.

Here's an example:

```
x_vars = []
y_vars = []

for i in range(2, noc + 2):
    x = StringVar()
    y = StringVar()
    xcoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=x)
    xcoord.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

    ycoord = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=y)
    ycoord.grid(column=2, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

    x_vars.append(x)
    y_vars.append(y)
```